# python theano Optimization failure due to: local_dot_to_dot22

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano

I just pip installed theano and tried to run theano.test(). It produced a very long log of errors and I copied the first part. I also tried a couple other examples - I have seen

```
"local_dot_to_dot22"
```

and

```
 "ValueError: invalid token "Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy1.5.2.2785.win-x86_64\Scripts" in ldflags_str: "-LC:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86_64\Scripts -lmk2_core -lmk2_intel_thread -lmk2_rt"
```

several times.

I'm using python 2.7 (canopy), scipy 0.15.1-2 and numpy 1.9.2-1. I am very new to theano. I appreciate if you can point me to the right direction. Thanks!

```
EEEEEERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: local_dot_to_dot22
ERROR:theano.gof.opt:Optimization failure due to: local_dot_to_dot22
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR:theano.gof.opt:TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1737, in process_node
replacements = lopt.transform(node)
File "c:\theano\theano\tensor\blas.py", line 1776, in local_dot_to_dot22
return [_dot22(x.dimshuffle('x', 0), y).dimshuffle(1)]
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\op.py", line 647, in __call__
no_recycling=[])
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\op.py", line 918, in make_thunk
no_recycling)
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\op.py", line 836, in make_c_thunk
output_storage=node_output_storage)
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1175, in make_thunk
keep_lock=keep_lock)
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1113, in __compile__
keep_lock=keep_lock)
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1541, in cthunk_factory
key = self.cmodule_key()
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1257, in cmodule_key
compile_args=self.compile_args(),
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 936, in compile_args
ret += x.c_compile_args()
File "c:\theano\theano\tensor\blas.py", line 652, in c_compile_args
return ldflags(libs=False, flags=True)
File "c:\theano\theano\tensor\blas.py", line 537, in ldflags
include_dir=include_dir)
File "c:\theano\theano\gof\utils.py", line 182, in rval
val = f(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\theano\theano\tensor\blas.py", line 597, in _ldflags
% (t, ldflags_str))
ValueError: invalid token "Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-    1.5.2.2785.win-x86_64\Scripts" in ldflags_str: "-LC:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86_64\Scripts -lmk2_core -lmk2_intel_thread -lmk2_rt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is problem caused by having spaces in your path, i.e. Canopy is installed in `C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy` but the Theano scripts don't work well with the space between `Program` and `Files`. Try uninstalling Canopy and reinstall in a directory with no space in the path.

You should also follow the other instructions for [installing Theano on Windows](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html). Unfortunately it's not as simple as just `pip install theano`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it worked!!! I cannot believe this was the reason causing theano to break! I wish that I asked this question easier! Thank you very much!

Comment: can confirm still this issue on python 3.x in 2019...4 years later and problem still isn't fixed

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to reinstall things, if they're heavy programs, for instance, affecting Window's registry and so, you can try **symbolic links**.

A symbolic link will create something similar to a shortcut to a folder, but seen as an actual folder by other applications.

So, you can do something like this:

- Run `cmd` as administrator
- User this command: `mklink /D "C:\LinkToProgramFiles" "C:\Program Files"`

And then, you start using "C:\LinkToProgramFiles" in your ldflags var.