# g++.exe: error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, keras

I am running this code on IPython. I am facing this issue. I will be thankful for suggestions or help to solve this issue.

I am using theano as a backend

```
import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pylab import *

# load the dataset

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data()
X = numpy.concatenate((X_train, X_test), axis=0)
y = numpy.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0)
```

> g++.exe: error: Amjad\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.3-64\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd: No such file or directory
>   g++.exe: error: Amjad\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.3-64\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

For g++ compilers, I had to install MinGW from [here](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (version without git).

Then add its "bin" dir to the PATH environment var. Normally it's the `C:\MinGW\bin` folder, or where you installed it.

(In case you have a g++ compiler already installed, add it's path to the environment var)

After that, if an error about `hypot` appears, you add this to a file named `.theanorc`, normally in `C:\Users\yourUser`. (Save it with notepad if you can't create it via windows explorer).

```
[gcc]
cxxflags = -D_hypot=hypot
```

> Always avoid installing anything in folders with spaces in their names! Theano won't recognize those folders and will bring errors. If you have problems with that, you can see these:

- [python theano Optimization failure due to: local_dot_to_dot22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462036/python-theano-optimization-failure-due-to-local-dot-to-dot22/43199865#43199865)
- [Installing Keras over Tensorflow on Windows 10 (Python 3.5.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825343/installing-keras-over-tensorflow-on-windows-10-python-3-5-3/43833878#43833878)